# Should i use Mysql or Firebase with big data?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-firestore, bigdata

i will make a project with big data for the first time. In the project i'd like to get data from electrical energy analysers of different customers every 10 seconds. So for 10.000 device for 10 years there will be 315 billion rows. I may have to scale up if the business idea goes better than i expect.

Can i use Mysql or firebase db to handle this kind of big data? What about the hosting service? Do i have to consider some parameters of the hosting service?

Comment: Let's see the main queries you will apply.  They may be trivial enough so that the engine does not matter.  Or they may be so messy that no engine will work.  Also, please provide a tentative `CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, as database for Big Data solution, Google is proposing [Cloud Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable). This database was designed for such projects. If you need SQL it can be easily connected to [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery) engine. You can easily connect it to Apache ecosystem.

If you want or have to use SQL database Google has [Spanner](https://cloud.google.com/spanner) which has unlimited scaling.

Both solution are not cheep, but only those can give enough scaling possibilities and can handle large workloads.

You can try other solutions like SQL instances or Firestore, or even Realtime Database (not sure what you mean by Firebase db), however if it appears that you need to scale up you will have lot more work to do.

Looking into short use case description Bigtable should be first thing to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need every 10 seconds' worth of data from 10 years ago?  I doubt it.

Do you need a graph of the data for last month?  Maybe.  But there aren't enough pixels to show all the datapoints at that granularity.

I would seriously look at summarizing the data promptly, then consider tossing the raw data.

315B rows will occupy more terabytes than can conveniently be housed on an off-the-shelf system today.  And think about how many hours it would take to scan all the data.  "Big data" often means "scan the data".  RDBMS often means "structure the data" for efficiency.

More on summary tables in MySQL:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

(And look around this site; I have advised several people on 'scientific' data like this.  Or give us more details and I will tailor my advice to you.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For the transient response of the network, i can use different kind of energy analysers so I decided 10s is really unneccessary. Even sample size of 1 hour will be enough. Thank you regardless.

Comment: @CagdasAkdemir - Another approach is to collect every 10 seconds, but not store the details; instead summarize and store only the avg, min, max, etc, for each hour.  This helps overcome flaky or spiky data.  (I don't know if your data is like that.)

Comment: A billion rows might take 100GB of disk -- quite practical these days.